# what does the imaginary part in the parsed svg path (line) mean?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, svg, xml-parsing

I have parsed a svg using both minidom and svgpathtools. For both of them i tried printing out the paths. Here, both printed coordinates but also have imaginary parts as well what does that mean? Any help would be appriciated.
Thanks in advance!

**CODE**

```
    from svgpathtools import svg2paths2
    paths, attributes, svg_attributes = svg2paths2('logo.svg')
    
    # print out the first path object it was in the SVG
    redpath = paths[0]
    redpath_attribs = attributes[0]
    print(redpath)
```

output->

```
    Path(Line(start=(296+120j), end=(410+120j)),
         Line(start=(410+120j), end=(410+392j)),
         Line(start=(410+392j), end=(296+120j)),
         Line(start=(216+120j), end=(102+120j)),
         Line(start=(102+120j), end=(102+392j)),
         Line(start=(102+392j), end=(216+120j)),
         Line(start=(255+219j), end=(207+337j)),
         Line(start=(207+337j), end=(259+337j)),
         Line(start=(259+337j), end=(282+392j)),
         Line(start=(282+392j), end=(328+392j)),
         Line(start=(328+392j), end=(255+219j)))
```

Comment: That's the way the [library is documented to work](https://github.com/mathandy/svgpathtools)

Comment: `296+120j` translates to `{x: 296, y: 120}`

Comment: thank you! @RobertLongson do you have any idea how we can manipulate these paths apart frm wsvg()..? wsvg() is overwtiting the svg i need to add various other parameters or lets say change the existing style attributes? is there a way out?

Comment: thnx! @Shreshth

Comment: That would seem to be a different question. Best ask that as a new question with your [mcve] for it.

Comment: @RobertLongson cool!